# Long running schedule job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I new to ROR. Wanted to ask something for confirmation. If I run long schedule job. Will it block others schedule job? I have others job running every 5 minutes, Plan to write something that easily run more than 3 hours. Will it block the 5 minutes job?

Comment: probably not, but depends on how your schedule the job. Speaking of which, how are you doing that?

Comment: I will add the job to schedule.rb in config folder.

Comment: I check the gemfile, I see we using this gem for background

gem 'whenever', :require => false
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'daemon-spawn

Not sure if related or not.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like a good way to do it. It probably is fine running multiple at the same time, but you could could check for yourself by making two jobs that write to the same file and then readinng the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`whenever` gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) is basically only a way to configure and handle [Cron jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

That said: At the given time Cron will just start and run a configured job. Cron will not block other jobs nor it cares if a job fails or if another job is still running.

Limiting factor might be:

- Memory/CPU consumption: Each job consumes memory/CPU. If there are too many jobs running at the same time your server might run out of memory or might have a high load. But this doesn't really block other jobs it just slows down the whole server.
- Database locks: If your jobs perform tasks that lock database tables other queries might be blocked and need to wait. But this is not Cron specific, this depends on what your code actually does.